# C# Linux get serial port information

Tags: c#, linux, serial-port, debian

I'm connecting with a USB device on a serial port using C# (using Linux Ubuntu). Now, I can connect just fine and communicate with the device. However, whenever i request the `serialport.portname` or `GetPortNames()`, I get a name like `/dev/ttyUSB0` or whatever.

It works, but I need to specifically identify a device whenever multiple different devices are connected. How can you get a device specific name like "prolific xxx"?

I read a couple of other posts but these were all very Windows specific. Quering the Win32 system manager and such. Is there a Linux specific or more generic way of doing this? Can´t seem to find an answer somehwere online.

Using a bin like `lsusb` does give me back specific names. So there must be way right?

Comment: Probably unrelated but maybe helpful to know: [If you *must* use .NET System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport)

Comment: Funny, the guy actually tells my experience with serialport so far in the first couple of sentences. As an embedded developer, I can relate. Thanks for the reply! His basestream explanation is actually quite handy